# Swagger url for self hosted servicesteack service

Tags: .net, web-services, servicestack, swagger

I am trying to use ServiceStack.Api.Swagger and 
by default swagger url is pre-populated with /swagger-ui/resources

While for self-hosted ServiceStack service it is available right under /resources

How can I change routing for self-hosted service for embedded swagger resources or update default swagger url. Routing update is preferable way as it is weird to have swagger under generic /resources url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue is now resolved](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/287) in **v4.0.41+** which is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet). You can workaround previous versions by specifying the `WebHostUrl` for your Service, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    WebHostUrl = "http://localhost:1337/api/"
});
```